# MVC Core: ViewComponent onload event equivalent

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I have a dropdown list inside an ASP.NET MVC Core project.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-md-10">
       @Html.DropDownListFor(t => t.AnimalTypeID, Model.AnimalTypeList, 
       new { onchange = "performStuff();" })
   </div>
</div>
```

The `onchange` event works like a charm, and hides certain containing-page fields (i.e. "fur colour" or "beak type" textboxes) depending on the dropdown selection.

I'd like to call the same functionality on the ViewComponent load/readiness also though. Is there a way to do this please?

I.e. I'm basically hoping to have the equivalent of this, if that might be possible please?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(t => t.AnimalTypeID, Model.AnimalTypeList, 
       new { onload="alertFunction();" ,onchange = "performStuff();" })

<script type="text/javascript">
    function alertFunction() 
    {
        alert('hello world!');
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Can you use jQuery in your solution?

Comment: Sure, yep that's an option I can take thanks.

Comment: Added more details in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC Core version of a drop down's Razor code is below.

```
<select asp-for="AnimalTypeId" asp-items="@Model.AnimalTypeList" onchange="alert('change');">
    <option>Please select</option>
</select>
```

However, select's JavaScript events are related to the element's behaviour only. If there is a need to show/hide some other fields on the page load, I would think it's the page main script's responsibility. You could either set show/hide params in your view model to control it from the back-end code, or use jQuery's

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {  /* Your function */ });
</script>
```

to control what elements should be hidden on the page load.